# Vaadin 7 - add more FontAwesome icons

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In my application I need more icons that present in  `com.vaadin.server.FontAwesome` enum.

For example I need these two icons:

```
http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icon/zoom-in/
http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icon/zoom-out/
```

How to add these icons to my Vaadin 7 application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+font+icons).

There is an alternative: Vaadin itself has a collection of font icons that you can use via the add-on. See [here](https://vaadin.com/icons)

Comment: Vaadin comes with FontAwesome. But I don't think it's the latest version. The referenced article show different ways to get font icons.

Comment: According to API, FontAwesome comes with Vaadin 7.2